# RabbitMq: How to receive message through DefaultConsumer?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Im using DefaultConsumer instead of QueueingConsumer becouse in this consumer i will connect to database and run procedures and after that i will send back ACK.

My question is very silly and i think easy...how to receive messages though class which extends DefaultConsumer?

When you use QueueingConsumer, you receive messages via QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the main:

```
 Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
 Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
 channel.queueDeclare("myQueue", false, false, false, null);
 MyConsumer consumer = new MyConsumer(channel);
 String consumerTag = channel.basicConsume("myQueue", false, consumer);
 System.out.println("press any key to terminate");
 System.in.read();
 channel.basicCancel(consumerTag);
 channel.close();
 connection.close();
```

The actual consumer class is:

```
public class MyConsumer extends DefaultConsumer {


    public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope,
            BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws java.io.IOException {

        /// byte[] body = body Message
        /// here you have your message

        getChannel().basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
    }


}
```

Comment: your message? if i understand right, DefaultConsumer is just for callback? How can i read received message in consumer?

Comment: I modified the Answer. You have your message inside the `handleDelivery`

Comment: System.out.println(body); prints something like this "[B@61ae8dfa"

Comment: Thats not my message...im new to java so maybe im something missin..i tried this with body but its same result String message = new String(body);

Comment: yes it is correct. The AMQP body message is an buffer, you have to write your message and decode it. For example in XML or JSON etc.